# Index 100 beyond bounds 0 ... 99 error in swipeDetected void

Tags: iphone, xcode, arrays, dictionary, bounds

Here it works fine. If I try to swipe right (back) from first object in index nothing happens.

```
- (void)swipeDetectedRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
if (detailIndex != 0)
    detailIndex--;  

Label.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Text"];
}
```

But when I'm on the last entry (nr 100) and swipes left, it crashes. Heres the code for left:

```
- (void)swipeDetectedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (detailIndex != [detailsDataSource count])
        detailIndex++;


    Label.text = [[detailsDataSource objectAtIndex: detailIndex] valueForKey:@"Text"];
}
```

And error message:

-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 100 beyond bounds [0 .. 99]'

How can I set bounds correcly so it won't swipe past the last object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)swipeDetectedLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

if (detailIndex != 99)
    detailIndex++;
}
```